# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Merge Sorted Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays nums1 and nums2 with elements m and n.nums1 array has extra space greater or equal to 'm+n'....for the addition of nums2 elements.
I have first added the elements from nums2 to nums1.Then I have sorted it.I am getting 'ArrayIndexOutOFBOundsException'.

```
class Solution
{
    public void merge(int[] nums1, int m, int[] nums2, int n)
    {
        int index=nums1.length-1;
        int temp;
        for(int i=nums2.length-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            nums1[index--]=nums2[i];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<nums1.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i+1;j<nums1.length;j++)
            {
                if(nums1[i]>nums1[j])
                {
                    temp=nums1[i];
                    nums1[i]=nums1[j];
                    nums1[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int j=0;j<nums1.length;j++)
        {
       System.out.print(nums2[j]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to make sure `nums2`'s length is equal to or greater than `nums1`'s length.

Answer (score 0):

problem related with your for statement

```
for (int i = nums2.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
    nums1[index--] = nums2[i];// if nums2.length longer than nums1 there will be exception 
}
```

end you're not merging it you're  writing nums2 over nums1
if you sure you have enough size for nums1 you have to add i to index;

```
for (int i = nums2.length -1; i >= 0; i--){
    nums1[index +i] = nums2[i];
}
```